# Child route handled by the same parent's component using react router

Tags: pagination, reactjs, parent-child, handler, react-router

I'm trying to define the routes for a paginated application.

```
/           -> handled by App
/page/:page -> also handled by App
```

These are what my routes look like:

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="paginated" path="page/:page" handler={App} />
    </Route>
);
```

This is what App looks like:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <RouteHandler/>
                Something...
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The problem here is that, as `paginated` is an `app`'s child route, that `Something...` in the componet gets rendered twice.

What I'm trying to acomplish here is to default to page 1 for the `app` route and to load the desired page for the `paginated` route, without loading twice.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `App` handler twice works the way you expect - it calls App`twice. However, the parent should only be used as the parent`Route Handler`, and the children use their own`Handlers`.

To get the initial page to load properly, use a `DefaultRoute` for the base path:

**routes**

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
        <Route name="paginated" path="page/:page" handler={Page} />
    </Route>
);
```

**app**

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**home**

```
var Home = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...Something...
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**page**

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...Something Completely Different...
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The React Router Default Handler Docs have a more substantial example:

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>

  <!--
    When the url is `/`, this route will be active. In other
    words, `Home` will be the `<RouteHandler/>` in `App`.
  -->
  <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>

  <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
  <Route name="users" handler={Users}>
    <Route name="user" handler={User} path="/user/:id"/>

    <!-- when the url is `/users`, this will be active -->
    <DefaultRoute name="users-index" handler={UsersIndex}/>

  </Route>
</Route>
```

Notice here that `<Route name="user" handler={User} path="/user/:id"/>` also has a default route, so when there is no `:id` match it has somewhere to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That was my first thought, but it wouldn't really work if I need to have nested routes in `paginated` ( which was actually the case ).

Answer (score -1):

At the end I came up with a solution using a redirection that allowed me to have the pagination and nested routes in the `paginated` one.

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Redirect from="/" to="paginated" params={{ page : 1 }} />

        <Route name="paginated" path="page/:page" handler={PaginationLoader} />
    </Route>
);
```